# Move DynamoDB table to S3 and update S3 automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to move my DynamoDB table (that has approx. 1000 rows) to S3 and everytime that the DynamoDB table gets updated, the file in S3 should be updated automatically.

What's a good way to implement this? Is my approach correct?

**Initial step:**

DynamoDB -> Glue/Data Pipeline -> S3

**Updating S3:**

DynamoDB (or DynamoDB Stream?) -> Lambda -> S3

Is it better to use Glue or Data Pipeline for moving? And is there a helpful link on how I can write a Lambda function for this case?

Answer (score 0):

As the number of rows is less, it is better to go ahead with Lambda based solution to avoid bootstrap time in Glue/Data Pipeline(uses EMR) and associated costs.

Doing CRUD operations on files is difficult, so, the lambda function can do a full table query everytime and write to a file and push to S3.

This function can happen on a schedule with 1 min frequency or more as you expect

Hope this helps!